# dbt: how can I rename tests to more understandable and readable custom names

Tags: dbt

The default names that dbt chooses for a test can be very long and when it's too long, dbt chooses to hash the last part.

Example:

> dbt_expectations_source_expect_table_row_count_to_equal_other_table_exponea_purchase_ref_test_exponea_sdv_orders_v___eventoccuredtime_yesterday_timestamp_AND_eventoccuredtime_today_timestamp___timestamp_yesterday_timestamp_AND_timestamp_today_timestamp_

How can I rename a dbt test (give a custom name) so that it is much more clear in the logs what a test was doing? (when it failed)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `name:` keyword to give a test a custom name:

```
tests:
  - dbt_expectations.expect_table_row_count_to_be_between: 
      name: exponea_purchase_row_count_yesterday_at_least_2500
      min_value: 2500
      row_condition: "timestamp >= {{ yesterday_timestamp() }}"
```

However for the `not_null` generic test this doesn't seem to work, so then you have to use `name` for the custom name and with `test_name` you can specify that you want `not_null`:

```
columns: 
  - name: timestamp
    description: the view is partitioned on this column
    tests: 
      - name: exponea_purchase_timestamp_not_null
        test_name: not_null
```

See also the dbt documentation here:
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/tests#define-a-custom-name-for-one-test

Or the explanation on the forum here:
https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/customizing-dbt-test-output-name/5550